# Attaching SQL Server database that is split into partitions

Tags: sql-server, database, partition

I have a trial version of SQL Server 2012 Enterprise on our test server that has expired. I would like to install a fresh copy of another Enterprise edition and attach the current db to the new one. I have done this locally by moving the mdf and ldf files to the new destination, then attaching the db through SSMS.

However the database on the test server is 700GB big and besides the mdf/ldf files there are 16 partitions (sql server database secondary data files). Will the same procedure apply in this case?

Comment: you sould probably create a backup and then restore it. That should make it easier.

Comment: Yes it will, I did this too with a 2TB database with several partitions and files.

Comment: Sere, use `create database ... for attach` and spell out all ndfs explicitly.

Comment: So after I move the 700GB files, all I have to do is something like this?    CREATE DATABASE MyDB2
ON PRIMARY
(FILENAME = 'c:\data\file1.mdf'),
(FILENAME = 'c:\data\file2.ndf'),
(FILENAME = 'c:\data\file3.ndf'),
(FILENAME = 'c:\data\file4.ldf')
for attach

Comment: Almost, remove the `PRIMARY`

Comment: Why don't you just pay for a developer license and quit trying to game the trial license? $50 versus how many hours of your time rebuilding a server?